# How to make modprobe ip_conntrack_ftp persist a reboot

Tags: drivers, ftp, iptables, modprobe

Sorry if this is a stupid question, but to get outbound active FTP connections through our firewall we need to run the following:

```
sudo modprobe ip_conntrack_ftp
```

I learned this trick from http://major.io/2007/07/01/active-ftp-connections-through-iptables/

In that article it says to persist it I should add

```
IPTABLES_MODULES="ip_conntrack_ftp"
```

to `/etc/sysconfig/iptables-config`

But I'm not sure that is right for Ubuntu, should I add `ip_conntrack_ftp` to the bottom of `/etc/modules` instead?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can add `ip_conntrack_ftp` to `/etc/modules`. Be attentive, you don't have to enter the modprobe command, just the name of kernel module!

Comment: Thanks. What do you mean? Can you just do `sudo ip_conntrack_ftp` insead of modprobe?

Comment: No, add `ip_conntrack_ftp` line to `/etc/modules`.

Comment: Oh, I understand what you mean now. Yes, I was aware of that, but thanks for confirming.

Answer (score 1):

Please note that if you are using a nonstandard / custom ftp port, you can just add `ports=<portnumber>` to the end of the line.

For a specific example, HylaFax works using FTP protocol and begins connections using port 4559 as the control port, and then opens passive FTP ports who-knows-where.  All you have to do with a custom FTP port of 4559 is `sudo vi /etc/modules` and then add a new line to the end of the file with `ip_conntrack_ftp ports=4559`.

Reboot and you should be good to go!

If you have more than one ftp service, you could also do `ports=21,4559` for instance.

For this to work, you will also need the corresponding `IPTABLES` rules:

`-A INPUT -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 4559 -j ACCEPT`